# How to install/enable Tidy extension in PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, php-7, php-extension, tidy

**Problem:**

Using tidy_parse_string() returns:

> call to undefined function

**Tried:**

Searching:

```
apt-cache search tidy
```

But i only see this php extension in the returned list :

> php5-tidy - tidy module for php5

How do i install the module for PHP 7.2?

I have tried enabling the module in php ini, in fpm 7.2 folder, by removing ;:

> ;extension=tidy

but there is no path to the extension so i guess it's not already installed.

**Clue:**
Tidy's own page says that you install with "configure options" - i have no idea how that pertains to apt installed packages.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.installation.php

**Elaboration:**

The package is listed here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/php7.2-tidy

But it does not show up when searching apt-get, even after updating the list. Only the php5 extension shows up?

Answer (score 7):

Hello I install tidy using this commands:

```
apt-cache search php7.2-tidy
apt-get update
apt-get -y install php7.2-tidy
```

Comment: Hi "apt-cache search php7.2-tidy" returns nothing. After i "apt-get update" i still get nothing so install gives me "E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-tidy'". I still only see a "php5-tidy - tidy module for php5" when searching for tidy? It's not there in the package list even though i update it. I can see the package here but it does not show up in the apt list: https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/php7.2-tidy

Comment: are you sure that you are using php7.2?

Comment: yes. "php -v" returns
PHP 7.2.2-3+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)